# Block locations for events and check conflicting location bookings

Tags: civievent

Is it possible in CiviEvent to prevent a location from being booked? Such as:

1. location isn't available
2. location is already booked for a different event
3. holidays

Would it also be possible to notify the users of this?

Answer (score 1):

Ren, welcome to SE! I think you may need to be clearer about your use case. In particular you say user twice, when I suspect the first may be an admin and the other a general user.

There isn't a mechanism to stop a venue being bookable, but you can make individual events not active in Manage Events >> edit specific event >> location tab. Does that do what you want. You can also allow booking only for a specific time in the online booking tab which may also do what you need. Making some assumptions here of course without more detail.

UPDATE based on comments below. There is currently no facility in CiviCRM to manage allocation of locations. It just holds location as a simple list and does not hold any time information against locations so cannot manage availability. You could write and extension, but it would be quite substantial as you would be doing a room booking system. If you have an external room booking system you might be able to do an integration as an extension but again quite a bit of work. I would suggest something external to CiviCRM as being the easiest option. Maybe a shared calendar.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. One of the things that we need to do is block or lock a location from being booked by different events for the same date and time. This is more like location/venue management than event management.

Comment: Please edit your original question and explain how your events are currently set up.  Users can't book a venue without you doing something to make that possible.  Just to be clear: are you talking about CiviEvents or are you referring to an extension?

Comment: The standard way of using Civi|CRM has an event booking system rather than a location booking system and the allocation of location to events isn't checked in the way that you want. But I think you need to describe your set up in more detail to see what might be done.

Comment: So far, we only have the basic core extensions and are only relying on what CiviEvents can do.  Is there an existing extension that can provide what we need? Or otherwise, how do we avoid booking a location that is already booked by an event?

Comment: Ren - we still need more information on the use case to advise you. Firstly when you are talking about users do you mean people setting up events or wanting places at the event. Normally we'd talk about booking for the second case but you may be using it for the first. This is how I think most people organise events - next comment...

Comment: Normal use case: An events organiser decides to hold an event. They sort out pricing, availability of location, number of places etc outside CiviCRM and then create the event in CiviCRM and make the event bookable. Then individual members/users can book the event up to the available places. CiviCRM checks the availability of the event, but not the location separately.

Comment: By user I do mean the people setting up the event, thanks. Our setup involves several people who might create different events and we want to prevent them from choosing a location that has already been used by another event. 

Is there an extension that can do this or is it possible to make one? Last choice would be to just coordinate among events organizers outside of CiviCRM as to the availability of locations.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will update my answer above, even though it is now quite negative!